# Arrayformula concatenating strings - will it slow down my sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Will an array formula like this one slow down my sheet? I am using it to concatenate 3 strings.

```
ARRAYFORMULA(M3:M & " - " & O3:O & " - " & V3:V)
```

I will have about 4 similar array formulas each in about 10 tabs with 5000 rows each.

Answer (score 1):

there are no heavy calculation in it so the answer is no - you should be just fine. the most performance consuming formulae class for a given scale (amount of rows/tabs you have)  are `IMPORTRANGE` `QUERY` and `VLOOKUP` or `MMULT`